# limit per district quota laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Question:** How can I dynamically limit using an array of districts quota, for example, if district A wants 3 applicants and district B wants 5 people, how can i get those applicants for a particular district that meet this criteria: age between 18 to 30/user input, total greater than 50/user input, order by total marks DESC, order By age. In other words get the best 3 from district A, and 5 from B at once into a datatable.

**Details**

1. I have a table for districts with number required(quota)column which is quota for how many applicants the district can take  [district table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J1XH.png)
2. I have a table for applicants which has age and other details (it belongs to district)
   [applicants table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GidI7.png)
3. I have a table for marks(recruitment table) is a child table of applicants,interviewer etc.
   [recruitment table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKuVl.png)
4. I have an ajax filter which has min age, max age, marks and district that populates the datatable.
   that works well

***What is happening now is, after user entering the minimum and maximum age, marks and selects districts, etc,***
it returns an array of districts.

- fetch from the table of districts, using the array of districts to pick the quota or required number
- still using the array of districts, i query the application table for applicant age, where I should use whereBetween Min and Max Age, I then use pass it as an array.
- query from Recruitment table whereIn ID is equal to Applicants Id,and where marks or total is greater than or equal to the mark that the user selected,

  ```
  if ($request->ajax()) {
       $filter_maxage = $request->get('filter_maxage');
       $filter_minage = $request->get('filter_minage');
       $filter_marks = $request->get('filter_marks');
       $filter_districts = $request->get('filter_districts');
       $filter_recruitmentcentres = $request->get('filter_recruitmentcentres');
       $filter_hasspecialattribute = $request->get('filter_hasspecialattribute');
       if ($filter_minage != '' and $filter_maxage != '' and $filter_marks != '' and $filter_districts != '' and $filter_hasspecialattribute == '' and $filter_recruitmentcentres == '') {
           $data = array();
           foreach ($filter_districts as $x) {
               $quotaz = District::find($x)->number_required;
               $d = Applicant::where('districts_id', $x)->whereBetween('age', [$filter_minage, $filter_maxage])->pluck('id')->toArray();
               $data = Finalrecruitment::with('interviewer', 'recruitmentcentre', 'applicant')->whereIn('applicants_id', $d)->where('total', '>=', $filter_marks)->orderBy('total', 'DESC')->limit($quotaz)->select('*');
           }
       } else {

           $data = Finalrecruitment::with('interviewer', 'recruitmentcentre', 'applicant')->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
               ->select('*');
       }
       return DataTables::of($data)
           ->addColumn('action', function ($users) {
           })
           ->make(true);
       echo json_encode($data);
   }
  ```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: I did but then I have to use union all and limit per district.. show me how maybe

Comment: If that's an angle you're interested in pursuing, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also, note that if you don't include @user in comments then we're less likely to see your comment.